# Kicad: PCBnew swap/change layer

Tags: pcb, kicad, silkscreen

How to change/swap layers on PCBnew using Kicad 5?

I want to swap the front drawing and front silk layers to F.SilkS, and in my case, I use an extra layer like Dwgs.User for dual silk printing: one blue for manufacturing, one white for the end user, like this:

[image: double silk screen PCB]

But double silk screen PCBs are expensive and harder to manufacture by standard prototype manufacturers, so I would like to merge Dwgs.User and F.SilkS; that way there is only one F.SilkS.

Comment: So is your problem merging two layers or switching between front and back or both?

Comment: Might it not be better to merge the gerber files, so the changes in Kicad from prototype to production boards would be minimal?

Answer (score 1):

With this script, we can change one layer to another:

```
sed 's/(layer Dwgs.User)/(layer F.SilkS)/g' board.kicad_pcb > board_swapped_silk.kicad_pcb
```

Note, this is for Kicad V5.xx, if anyone want to contribute for V6.

Comment: How does it deal with the bottom layer text being mirrored/reversed?

Comment: It does not, it simply moves Dwgs.User layer to F.Silks, but as both are intended to be front silk in my case, it's all good.

Comment: Why did you say "back silk layer" in your question?